# Three.js Fail to Load a large 3D model with JSONLoader

Tags: javascript, three.js

So I'm trying to load a 3D model(file.json) with JSONLoader. It's about 40mb, but the model doesn't show up on the webpage, and my laptop starts to heat up. The console doesn't tell any error or warning, I wonder what should I do to load my model.

```
    // -----------  render --------------
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas:document.getElementById('myCanvas'), antialias:true});
    renderer.setClearColor(0x000000);
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

// -----------  camera --------------

    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(35, window.innerWidth/ window.innerHeight, 0.1, 3000);

// -----------  scene --------------

    var scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // create light
    var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xC2ffe3, 0.5);
    scene.add(light);

    var light1 = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff,0.5);
    scene.add(light1);


    var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    // load a resource
    loader.load(
// resource URL
        'untitled.json',

// onLoad callback
        function ( geometry, materials ) {

            var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, materials);
            scene.add( mesh );
            mesh.position.z = -10;
        },
    );





    render();
    function render(){

        renderer.render(scene, camera);
        requestAnimationFrame(render);
    }


</script>enter code here
```

Comment: [`JSONLoader.load`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/loaders/JSONLoader) takes four parameters: `url`, `onLoad`, `onProgress`, `onError`. Try adding progress and error callbacks (just like you did for `onload` so you can catch if the `load` call results in an error, or if it's simply taking a (really) long time.

Comment: problem solved. Yeah, it's just taking really long time... thank you